# Edit a .clog file in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently working with the PIXet Pro software and a Timepix detector to perform data analysis.
My output file from the detector is a .clog file (you can open it as a .txt) organized as follows:
Every row corresponds to a cluster of pixels, and the data is shown as [x,y,value].

I would like to edit this file in order to generate a raster plot of the full pixel matrix (256x256 pix), as well as an energy histogram (summing each cluster value, i.e. ever "value" in a row and making it an histogram entry).

How can I do this? I'd like to know how to rewrite my data in a more useful format and which format to use.

[.clog file to download](https://gofile.io/d/LWZk4A)

Comment: So what's wrong with loading in the contents from the .clog file and modifying it within R?

Comment: The presence of square brackets, spaces as dividers between entries etc.
I've always used a "matrix" dataframe, with rows and columns and nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to do this, and I will explain how so that someone can use it too.

First of all i removed every "non data" character and used spaces as a separator.
Then i opened the file in R by inserting it ina 768 columns long dataframe (3 vlaues x 256 pixels), with NA for every missing value.

The parsing is done by chosing every third column starting from the 1st (for X), from the 2nd (for Y) and 3rd (for VALUE).